# Calculating number of free variables in rotation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, rotations

In Modern Robotics, there is a line that says, because we have 3 unitary constraints, and 3 orthogonality constraints for rotation matrices, summarized by the equation $R^T R = I$, and $R$ is 9-dimensional, that means $R$ has 3 free variables.

My understanding of free variables comes from linear algebra, where the number of "free variables" is essentially the dimensionality of the null space.

In order to argue that the previous setup has a 3-dimensional nullspace, the 3 unitary and 3 orthogonality constraints must be linearly independent constraints.

However, looking at these constraints:
[image]

These constraints are quadratic in terms of the rotation matrix variables. Therefore, linear independence does not make sense as a concept here.

How do I rigorously argue that $R$ has 3 "free" variables in this setting? How do you define "free" variables in a general way with non-linear constraint equations, instead of using the nullspace, which is a concept for linear constraint equations?

Comment: The matrix exponential representation of an arbitrary rotation matrix may provide the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Exponential_map. The comments near the end of that section further suggest the following intuition: An arbitrary rotation requires a direction in space to be specified, along with the amount of rotation. The former gives two parameters, the latter one.

Comment: @Semiclassical Seems circular to me... the representation you're talking about is the axis angle representation. But then we need to explain why axis angle represents all rotations

Comment: Also still missing a bit of rigor. With linear equations, this idea of "free variables" is made very rigorous by nullspace, by I'm not sure what the corresponding idea is here

Comment: [Euler's rotation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem) should probably be invoked here to justify that all rotations are of exponential form. I also don't think there's any reason to think of "free variables" in reference to null space specifically: The space of rotation matrices is 3-dimensional.

Comment: @Semiclassical Okay but I guess the point is, the author seems to be saying "We have 6 non-linear constraints for 9 variables" is enough justification to say that there are 3 free variables. To be more precise, the only thing you can conclude from the quoted statement is that there are *at least* 3 free variables. But these constraints may be "redundant" in some sense, so we need something else (like Euler's rotation theorem) to prove exactly 3 free variables

Comment: Is that correct?

Comment: Actually I can't even figure out why you could claim there are at least 3 free variables. For linear equations, the argument comes from back substitution, but there is nothing analogous to back substitution for nonlinear systems

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate "rigorous" notion to apply here is that $O(3)$, the set of rotations in three dimensions, is a three-dimensional [Lie Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group), which in particular means that it is a three-dimensional [Smooth Manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold). This means essentially that $O(3)$ is "locally" described by three smooth coordinate functions, but this takes a bit of work to make precise.

The standard way to show that $O(3)$ is indeed a manifold is through the preimage theorem, which states that, given a smooth map $f:M\to N$ between manifolds, and $x\in M$ is a regular value, then $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is a smooth manifold of dimension $\dim f^{-1}(\{x\})=\dim M-\dim N$ (and in fact a smooth submanifold of $M$).

Here, we can identify the space of $3\times 3$ matrices with $\mathbb{R}^9$ and the set of symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices with $\mathbb{R}^6$, and consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^9\to\mathbb{R}^6$ defined by $f(A)=A^TA$ under this identification, so that $O(3)$ is then the level set $f^{-1}(I_3)$. The level set theorem then states that $O(3)$ is a smooth manifold if $I_3$ is a regular value of $f$, i.e. if the Jacobian of $f$ is surjective on all of $O(3)$.